# How to prevent the action button column from being printed or exported when printing in laravel datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

So I have displayed data into datatables with laravel. In the datatables I added an action column, which contains edit and delete buttons. I also added some plugins for printing and export. Like this.
[image: preview]

When I want to print/export, the action column are also printed. How do you make sure that column doesn't print?

[image: printed]

I have added the `data-dt-noprint="true"` attribute to the `<td>` tag, but it has no effect

Here's my `<td>`

```
<td data-dt-noprint="true">
   <!-- Tombol Edit -->
   <a href="{{ route('karyawan.edit', $item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>

   <!-- Tombol Hapus -->
   <form action="{{ route('karyawan.destroy', $item->id) }}" method="POST"
         style="display: inline-block;" class="form-delete"
         data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
         @csrf
         @method('DELETE')
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete"
               data-id="{{ $item->id }}">Hapus</button>
   </form>
</td>
```

and here is my `<script>` for datatables

```
$(function() {
   $("#table-karyawan")
     .DataTable({
         responsive: true,
         paging: true,
         lengthChange: false,
         autoWidth: false,
         searching: true,
         ordering: true,
         info: true,
         buttons: [
            "copy",
            "csv",
            "excel",
            "pdf",
            "print",
         ],
    })
    .buttons()
    .container()
    .appendTo("#table-karyawan_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)");
});
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the columns that you want to print using

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copyHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 5 ]
            }
        },
        'colvis'
    ]
} );
```

Please refer the below link
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html